# Returns [object HTMLSpanElement]

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form>
   <table>
     <tr>
        <td>Distance:</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="distance" onKeyUp="calculate();">m</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Time:</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="time" onKeyUp="calculate();">s</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Speed:</td>
        <td><span id="speed">21</span><span id="unit">&nbsp;m/s</span></td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

   var calculate = function() {
      var distance = document.getElementById("distance").value;
      var time = document.getElementById("time").value;
      var speed = distance/time;}
      if (speed=="Infinity" || speed=="NaN") {
         document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML="Invalid Input";
         document.getElementById("unit").innerHTML="";
      } else {
         document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML=speed;
      }

</script>
```

I am making a simple speed calculator but it isn't working. The output comes **[object HTMLSpanElement]**
Any help will be appreciated for I am new to javascript.

Comment: Why do you have a } after distance/time? Shouldn't that be after the if?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `speed` in the last line is not the same as the one you set because it's in a different scope.

Try this:

```
var calculate = function() {
  var distance = document.getElementById("distance").value;
  var time = document.getElementById("time").value;
  var speed = distance/time;

  if (speed=="Infinity" || speed=="NaN"){
    document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML="Invalid Input";
    document.getElementById("unit").innerHTML="";
  }else{
    document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML=speed;
  }
};
```

Comment: If `speed` was not defined, you would get a JavaScript error.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is scope:

```
var calculate = function() {
  var distance = document.getElementById("distance").value;
  var time = document.getElementById("time").value;
  var speed = distance/time;
}

// speed is not within the right scope anymore 
// because you closed the function above!
if (speed=="Infinity" || speed=="NaN"){
  document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML="Invalid Input";
  document.getElementById("unit").innerHTML="";
}else{
  document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML=speed;
}
```

Because your script runs in `document`, the value of `speed` is resolved as the element `<span id="speed" ... >`.

Move the last if-statement inside the function:

```
var calculate = function() {
  var distance = document.getElementById("distance").value;
  var time = document.getElementById("time").value;
  var speed = distance/time;

  if (speed=="Infinity" || speed=="NaN"){
    document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML="Invalid Input";
    document.getElementById("unit").innerHTML="";
  }else{
    document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML=speed;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-obvious issue. It helps with proper indentation

```
var calculate = function() {
  var distance = document.getElementById("distance").value;
  var time = document.getElementById("time").value;
  var speed = distance/time;
}

if (speed=="Infinity" || speed=="NaN"){
  document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML="Invalid Input";
  document.getElementById("unit").innerHTML="";
} else{
  document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML=speed;
}
```

The value of `speed` that you are assigning is not actually defined anywhere in your code. The `speed` from inside of `calculate` is not used because it is scoped within the function. The `speed` you are actually assigning is one that the browser automatically creates based on the `id` you have given to your element.

If you put the assignment within your `calculate`, the problem will be fixed.

```
var calculate = function() {
  var distance = document.getElementById("distance").value;
  var time = document.getElementById("time").value;
  var speed = distance/time;


  if (speed=="Infinity" || speed=="NaN"){
    document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML="Invalid Input";
    document.getElementById("unit").innerHTML="";
  } else{
    document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML=speed;
  }
}
```